# Queuing Theory - Mean Service rate

Tags: queueing-theory

I am working on this problem and I don't really know how to use the information given.

Interarrival time (min) 15-6-12-13-9-14-9-7-15-14-11-12

Service time (min) 11-15-10-14-7-15-13-14-2-14-6-16

I'm supposed to calculate the average waiting time and some probability but I'm stuck because I can't figure out to calculate the mean service time (µ) but I've never done that from using a table. We have always been given the mean service time.

English isn't my first language and there isn't much information to be given in my native one.

Is there a formula that I'm over looking? I have calculated the arrival rate, (λ) from this, and I think I've done that correctly.
λ = 5.22 customers/hour

EDIT: The shop opens at t = 0 and closed after the last customer left.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm going to assume that you mean "9-14" instead of "914". Also, what exactly is service time?

Comment: Uh, I've translated it, but it's the time it takes to serve one customer. Is there another phrase that is better?
And yes, that is correct it's supposed to be 9-14

Comment: Is the service time supposed to be included in the waiting time? For instance, does the first customer wait $11$ minutes or $0$ minutes?

Comment: Like I understand it, the first customer arrives after 15 minutes, and is serviced for 11 minutes. The second customer arrives after 15+6 minutes and is servied after the previous customer has left.

Comment: If $W_n$ represents the waiting time in the queue of job $n$ (not including its service time) then you likely are supposed to iterate the equation $$W_{n+1} = \max[W_n + S_n - X_n, 0]$$ where $S_n$ is the service time of job $n$ and $X_n$ is the inter-arrival time for job $n$ (so $X_1=15, X_2=6, ...$ and $S_1=11, S_2=15, ...$). Note $W_1=0$ since the first job arrives to an empty system and hence is served immediately with no time in queue.  After that, you can compute $\frac{1}{12}\sum_{i=1}^{12} W_i$. There are no probabilities to calculate here, since there is no probability model given.

Comment: But how do I calculate the mean service rate? In all of the equations we have been given I need to know the mean service rate and the arrival rate.

Comment: $\mu$ is typically the mean service rate rather than the mean service time.  Have you tried computing the average service time from the service time data you were given?

Comment: Average service time is lambda right?
This is all so confusing for a non-english speaker :(
I calculated lambda to be 5.22 customers per hour.

Comment: The approach you want to use is described by Michael. I will here explain something about the rates. Typically, $\lambda$ is the arrival rate and $\mu$ is the service rate. Now, a rate is the inverse of a mean. The mean interarrival time is $(15 + 6 + \cdots + 11 + 12)/12 = 11.416$ minutes, or $0.1903$ hours. So, the arrival rate $\lambda = 1/0.1903 = 5.26$ customers per hour. The mean service time is $(11 + 15 + \cdots + 6 + 16)/12 = 11.42$ minutes, or $0.1903$ hours. The service rate is therefore $\mu = 1/0.1903 = 5.26$ customers per hour. It is a **coincidence** that $\lambda = \mu$.